# Password Protect Api for Folder in Android

Tags: android

I want to put password for a folder on SD-Card in my Android phone. I am looking Android API for password protect to a folder but i didn't get any solution, so if any one have an idea could you please share with me. Any idea is appreciated.

Thanks,
Mohan.

Comment: You could just encrypt the password, so if anyone reads the encrypted password, it would be useless. You would need to decrypt it for you to use and make sure the encryption key is safely stored.

Comment: Like a .zip file with a password, or do you want to build something yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, except perhaps via your own custom build of the Android OS.

An app has no means of preventing other apps from accessing specific portions of external storage, and an app has no means of preventing the user from accessing specific portions of external storage when mounted as a drive or volume on a host computer.

Comment: Hi CammonsWare i saw an app in Google Playstore which is i placed the link below, i want to know how it working, what is the internal logic.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mwgo.filelocker

Comment: @MohanRao: Based on the description, they are encrypting the files. This does not prevent other apps, or the user, from accessing the files; it would prevent them from doing anything useful with the files.

Comment: Thank you so much CammonsWare for your valuable response. Can you guide me how to write my own app like this link  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mwgo.filelocker . If you have any sample links could you please share with me.